# Printing From SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 on Windows Server 2003 R2

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

When I print from report manager in reporting services (2008) the quality of the output is terrible with fonts that look great on screen being very blurry and badly sized.

Is there a known issue here?

Comment: What browser are you using? My SSRS reports only seem to look "correct" in IE. Also, what fonts are you using in your reports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have been looking into the printing issue where fonts get ruined when print a SSRS 2008 report using report manager.

The same reports printed fine using

- SSRS 2005 on an XP machine
- SSRS 2008 on a Windows 7 machine.

So it appears to be something specific to SSRS 2008 on Windows Server 2003.

Reading what other people have experienced there are a few ideas about how to fix it.

- [Its an issue with the display
  resolution of the host machine.“This
  may explain why on the server if you
  restart SSRS from within a console
  that has a resolution ratio of 1.33
  like 1024x768 (thereby matching the
  320/240 default size by ratio) the
  issue is resolved.”](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/482312/ssrs-report-font-rendering-issue)
- [It may be fixed in SQL Server 2008 Cumulative update (we have R2 though so presumably not relevant)](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/403130/sql-reporting-services-2008-print-rendering-issue-font-replacement-font-missing-character-space-compression)
- [People got it magically fixed when the security update applied (but then some people say it comes back again)](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/403130/sql-reporting-services-2008-print-rendering-issue-font-replacement-font-missing-character-space-compression)
- [It’s something to do with people logged into server via terminal services. When they get booted off its all fine again](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/c0439b1a-b3e4-408e-ab64-a3f2fae2856b?prof=required)

Of the above the first one is the only one I have not eliminated so will try that.